# Get information about the currently extended GPO

Tags: c#, .net, group-policy, mmc, snap-in

We are currently developing an MMC SnapIn Extension, that extends multiple group policy objects (GPOs), like you can see it in that image below:

[Group Policy Management Editor - Extended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9jAS.png)

Thecnology is MMC 3.0, .NET 3.5, C#, VS2013. The extension is available on all GPOs.

The main class of the extension looks like this (in an anonimized way)

```
[SnapInSettings("{3B6F64DC-4572-4A64-957A-E8A9E2FEBD54}", DisplayName = "DisplayName", Description = "MMC Snap-In")]
[ExtendsNodeType("{8FC0B739-A0E1-11D1-A7D3-0000F87571E3}")]
[ExtendsNodeType("{D37CB93E-0DDC-4204-AA04-C3D70B01A7D8}")]
public class ExtensionSnapIn : NamespaceExtension
{
}
```

Everything works fine except I cannot determine which GPO is the parent of the currently opened extension. I would like to know this because I have to write into the registry to the following path: HKLM\Software\Company\Product\Client Group Policy\[GPOID]\

I would like to have this ID dynamically: [I'm looking look for the highlighted GUID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClhNp.png)

I have tried a lot of things with no result at all:

- In the ExtensionSnapIn class there is an inherited PrimaryScopeNode property which has a NodeType property which is a GUID. Unfortunately, this property always returns 00000000-000-0000-0000-000000000000. However the documentation says that about the PublishesNodeTypeAttribute:

> If a node does not have this attribute, it cannot be registered as an
>   extensible node.

- Whenever I'm trying to read from the PrimaryNode.SharedData like this:

Sample:

```
//private const string shdata = "CCF_SCE_GPT_UNKNOWN";
//private const string shdata = "CCF_SNAPIN_CLASSID";
//private const string shdata = "CCF_DISPLAY_NAME";
//private const string shdata = "CCF_NODETYPE";
//private const string shdata = "CCF_SZNODETYPE";
//private const string shdata = "CCF_SNAPIN_CLASSID";
//private const string shdata = "CCF_DISPLAY_NAME";
//private const string shdata = "CFSTR_DSOBJECTNAMES";
private const string shdata = "CCF_SCE_GPT_UNKNOWN";

public ExtensionSnapIn()
{
    this.PrimaryNode.SharedData.Add(new SharedDataItem(shdata));
}

protected override void OnInitialize()
{
    SharedDataItem sharedDataItem = this.PrimaryNode.SharedData.GetItem(shdata);
}
```

I'm always getting an exception. For CCF_NODETYPE, CCF_SZNODETYPE, CCF_SNAPIN_CLASSID, CCF_DISPLAY_NAME I'm getting this:

> The following clipboard format is reserved for use by MMC:
>   CCF_DISPLAY_NAME. Specify another clipboard format.

The rest of the clipboard formats just give a PrimarySnapInDataException with this stack trace:

> at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.SharedDataItem.GetData()    at
>   Balabit.SyslogNgAgent.MMC.ExtensionSnapIn.OnInitialize() in
>   c:\Source\Bergholz\Client\Client.Product\Main\src\MMC\ExtensionSnapIn.cs:line
>   65    at
>   Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Advanced.NamespaceExtension.ProcessNotification(Notification
>   notification)    at
>   Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Internal.SnapInClient.Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Internal.IMessageClient.ProcessNotification(Notification
>   notification)    at
>   Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Executive.SnapInInitializationOperation.OnStart()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Executive.RunningOperationsTable.EnqueueOperation(Operation
>   operation)    at
>   Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Executive.NamespaceExtensionComponentData.GetScopeNodeForExpand(IDataObject
>   dataObject, IntPtr hScopeItem)    at
>   Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Executive.ComponentData.OnExpand(IDataObject
>   dataObject, Boolean isExpanding, IntPtr hScopeItem)    at
>   Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Executive.ExpandMmcNotification.OnNotify(IntPtr
>   dataObject, IntPtr arg, IntPtr param)    at
>   Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Executive.MmcNotifyTarget.Notify(IntPtr
>   dataObject, NotificationType eventType, IntPtr arg, IntPtr param)

I have googled this problem for days, and I have read tons of articles about MMC Extension SnapIns, and GPO, but I have not yet found any usable solutions for my problem.

Thanks for your help in advance.